# PHP Regex URL Not Only href but plaintext URLs also

Tags: regex

How would I write some regex that would include plaintext urls.

If I have the following content:
Please paste this url `http://google.com` into your browser to view.

How would I parse that url without the a tag/href?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Complicated or very simple, e.g. [`\bhttps?://\S+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/iV8hQ3/1), depending on your actual needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your actual needs, you could come up with a very simple regex:

```
$regex = '~          # delimiter
          \b         # a word boundary
          https?://  # http:// or https://
          \S+        # not a whitespace, one or more times
          \b         # another word boundary
          ~x';       # delimiter + freespace modifier
preg_match_all($regex, $your_string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Admittedly, this will also match non-sense urls (see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iV8hQ3/2)), but depending on what you want to do with it afterwards, it might be more readable and maintanable than the official standard. Also, have a look at this [wonderful website](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex), where the author offers a table of different approaches.